# Java Image Output choose deleted image

Tags: java, image

I have a button that choose a file.It pop and show its data in image but whenever I delete the image generated in the program and choose a new file it keep poping the deleted image but it shows the correct output data of the new selected file.

I have a button that delete the image file.

```
  (eventSource == fcButton) {

        try {
            if (myWav.getJFileChooser().showOpenDialog(AudioDriver.this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                    File file = myWav.getFileFromGUI();
                                    try{

                                        AudioDriver Data = new AudioDriver(file, "out.png");

                                    }catch(IOException ioe) {
                                     showError(ioe);
                                       } catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException uafe) {
                                   showError(uafe);
                                   }
                                    try{
                                        bi = loadImage(".....\\out.png");

                                    }catch(IOException ioe){
                                        showError(ioe);
                                    }

                                     jLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(bi));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code,
maybe this is the code you are looking for:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class Start extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4450256642721274436L;

    public Start() {

        setSize(300, 150);

        setTitle("Demo");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setVisible(true);

        JButton button = new JButton();

        button.setText("Open");
        button.setBounds(100, 40, 75, 30);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG File (.png)", "png"); //if necessary

                chooser.setDialogTitle("Open");
                chooser.setApproveButtonText("Open");
                chooser.setFileFilter(filter); //if necessary
                chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY); //if necessary

                int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

                if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

                    new ImageViewer();

                }

            }

        });

        getContentPane().add(button);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Start();

    }

}

class ImageViewer extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2820136869820714996L;

    public ImageViewer() {

        //do something here...

    }

}
```